# Posting Products to Facebook using the facebook-nodejs-business-sdk

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, facebook, facebook-nodejs-business-sdk

I have been trying to set up the facebook APIs to work with my react app. I succeeded pulling the products from an existing catalogue. When posting the product, I am first saving it to my database for image processing in accordance to image rules. After this is done, I pull the data from the database to post onto facebook. The api returns a 200 ( success) but I dont see the product in the catalogue I chose even after 2 days. Has anyone else experienced this?

I have a feeling my problem is rooting from the URL where the product is to be fetched from for that particular feed, but I dont understand this enough to think of a solution. Since this is localhost testing, how do I go about the product feed being fetched from a csv file online?

```
const productFeed = new ProductFeed(null, {parent_id: catalogId});
      productFeed.setData({
        name: 'Localhost Shopool Data',
        schedule: {
          interval: 'HOURLY',
          url: 'http://localhost:3030/',
        }
      });

      console.log(productFeed)
      
      if (productFeed.parent_id > 0){
        const productFeedItem = new ProductFeedItem(null, {parent_id: productFeed.parent_id});
        productFeedItem.setData({
          // Set your product details here
          name: JSON.stringify(productData.prod_name),
          description: JSON.stringify(productData.prod_desc),
          image_url: JSON.stringify(productData.pimg_url),
          url: '',
          price: JSON.stringify(productData.prod_price),
          currency: 'KES',
          availability: JSON.stringify(avalability),
          condition: 'new',
          inventory: JSON.stringify(productData.prod_qty),
        });
        await productFeedItem.update();
        console.log(productFeedItem)
      }
      
      res.status(200).json({message:"Posted to facebook successfully"});
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({message:'Error posting product to Facebook catalog'});
    }
```

The code seems to run all the way to the status 200. I have my doubts about the product feed section.

Comment: UPDATE: The way to do this is using csv files. Add the product to a CSV file and then upload it onto facebook. Works like a charm.